Why $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0$ in multivariate implicit differentiation?
Stuart's textbook goes as follows.
$F$ is as below
$$ F(x,y,z)=0,
$$
and $z$ can be expressed as below.
$$ z=f(x,y).
$$
Also, when $F$ and $f$ are differentiable, $F$ can be differentiated using the chain rule.
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x}\frac{\partial x}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}\frac{\partial y}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 0$$
Because $$\frac{\partial x}{\partial x}=1$$
and because
$$\frac{\partial y}{\partial x}=0,$$
the above can be summarised as below:
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial F}{\partial z}\frac{\partial z}{\partial x} = 0.$$

But, what I don't understand is why $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ has to be zero.
If $z$ can be expressed as an equation of $x$ and $y$, then can the equation be rearranged to make $y$ a dependent variable?
For example, if $z = 3x + y$  then $y$ can be defined as $y= z - 3x$.
Then $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x}$ will be $-3$.
I don't really understand why $\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x} = 0$.
Perhaps I'm too stupid to understand.
Please, help.

The implicit function theorem tells you that under some assumptions, there exists a function $Z(x,y)$ such that $F(x,y,z)=0$ if and only if $F(x,y,Z(x,y))=0$. The function $Z$ is not the same as the variable $z$, but rather a local way to express the dependence of $z$ on $x,y$ as you restrict yourself to the surface $F(x,y,z)=0$.
Now for the chain rule. Let $H(u,v,w)$ be a function of three variables, and let $U(x,y,z),V(x,y,z),W(x,y,z)$ be functions of three variables. The chain rule is a theorem which allows to differentiate the composite function:
$$G(x,y,z):=H(U(x,y,z),V(x,y,z),W(x,y,z)).$$
When using both the chain rule and implicit function theorem, it's just important to do proper book keeping of who the functions/variables are, so that variables don't get mixed up with each other. In your case, $U(x,y,z)=x, V(x,y,z)=y$, and $W(x,y,z)=Z(x,y)$ (and not $W(x,y,z)=z$). This makes all the difference when differentiating. That's why $\partial V/\partial x=0$ - since you're differentiating $y$ itself, and not some function $Y(x,z)$.
This might all seem like cosmetics, but this is really the heart of both the chain rule and the implicit function theorem - keeping track of what's a variable and what's a function in your setting. Saying $z=z(x,y)$ is not a precise thing, because it naturally mixes variables and functions. It's healthier to denote $Z(x,y)$ and think of $Z$ as we did above - this is the relation which produces $F(x,y,Z(x,y))=0$ along the surface. Same for $u, v, w$ vs. $U, V, W$.
From my experience, $90\%$ of confusion about these exercises arises from not being careful with these notations. Hope this helps!

Thanks so much for the answer. I'm reading it like 5 times now. I'll read it until I fully understand. Thank you!
